# Zend_DBTable relationships

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, relationship

I know that the question has certainly be asked several times, but I can't find (understandable) responses to it.

I've to tables 'spots' & 'members' and a relation table 'spotmembers'.

In the zend framework, i'm using Zend_Db_Table but I don't manage to retrieve objects from my relationship in my requests.

Here are my classes :

```
class Model_DbTable_Member extends Zend_Db_Table {
protected $_name = 'members';
protected $_primary = 'id';
protected $_dependentTables = array('Model_DbTable_SpotMember');

class Model_DbTable_SpotMember extends Zend_Db_Table {
protected $_name = 'spotmembers';
protected $_primary = 'id';
protected $_referenceMap = array(
    'Spot' => array(
        'columns' => 'id_spot',
        'refTableClass' => 'Model_DbTable_Spot',
        'refColumns' => 'id'
    ),
    'Member' => array(
        'columns' => 'id_member',
        'refTableClass' => 'Model_DbTable_Member',
        'refColumns' => 'id'
    )
);
```

I would like to make a request in order to retrieve Member objects related to a Spot object, any idea about how to do that ?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this for a simple relation **OneToMany**:

```
$Spot = new Model_DbTable_SpotMember();
$SpotDB = $Spot->find($id)->current();

$Members = $SpotDB->findParentModel_DbTable_Member();
Zend_Debug::dump($Members->toArray();
```

For a relation **ManyToMany**, somethink like that:

```
$Members = $Spot->findModel_DbTable_MemberViaModel_DbTable_SpotMember('MemberName','MemberInfo');
Zend_Debug::dump($Members->toArray();
```

All documentation, can be found here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html

Example #9:

```
$bugsTable = new Bugs(); // Your "Spot"
$bugsRowset = $bugsTable->find(1234); // Loading "Spot" and retreive RowSet
$bug1234 = $bugsRowset->current(); // Retrieve

$productsRowset = $bug1234->findManyToManyRowset('Products', // Your "Members" table
                                             'BugsProducts', // YOur "relation" table
                                             'Bug'); // The crurent table "Spot"
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Model_DbTable_SpotMember::findParentModel_DbTable_Member() ... I already catch this error when trying to use zend magical functions. Any idea ?

Comment: Sorry, my fault... See the edited source and use the `$SpotDB` returned by `find()->current()`

Comment: It works ! What if I want to get all members related ? cause this current() only catch the first row of the rowset. Thanks

Comment: Normally, you have all "Members" in `$Members`... I just watch you ave a "ManyToMany" relation... My Example work for a relation "OneToMany". I'll putting more information in answer.

Comment: Once again : Fatal error: Call to undefined method Model_DbTable_SpotMember::findModel_DbTable_MemberViaModel_DbTable_SpotMember(), I'm really not used to this kind of relationship management... any idea ?

Comment: What the class that Model_DbTable_SpotMember extends (Zend_Db_Table) ? Can you show the methods of this class ; You need `findManyToManyRowset`. I put a sample from Zend Doc in my answer.